# How to plot data from multiple data files on one plot with a loop (CTD data) on python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have multiple `cnv` files and I would like the plot the temperature variable from each file onto one plot. I have a loop to open the multiple files however, when I plot it, it plots each dataset on a new plot so I end up with multiple figures instead of one.

Here is the script:

```
from seabird.cnv import fCNV
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from seabird.cnv import fCNV
import glob

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('dSBE19plus*.cnv')) #reads multiple files
filenames = filenames[0:15]                      #16 files
for f in filenames:
    print(f)

    data = fCNV(f)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylabel('average')
    ax.plot(data['tv290C'], data['prdM'],'b')
```

Comment: Move `fig, ax  = plt.subplots()` and `ax.set_ylabel('average')` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new plot with each iteration of your `for` loop.  Bring the plot creation outside of the loop.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel('average')

for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    data = fCNV(f)

    ax.plot(data['tv290C'], data['prdM'],'b')
```